# Python folder recursion

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm getting lost... I'll post what I tried, but it didn't work.

So I have to get through 3 folders.
Let's say there is the main folder(label it main for this) and 100 sub folders to the main folder(1-100 labeled), but I need to get inside those subfolders(labeled A,B,C,D,E..etc for what I need, won't go more than D) and I need to read the files inside the subfolders A,B,C,D which are .txt folders.

So 
Main--->1-100--->A,B,C,D for each 1-100---> read .txt folders

```
import os
import glob
os.chdir("/Main")
for folders in glob.glob("20*"):
    print(folders)
```

I tried this with an extra code to get in the subfolders

```
 for folder in folders:
      glob.glob("tracking_data*")
      print(folder)
```

Which didn't give me what I needed. The first code works fine, the 2nd code was supposed to give me a list of tracking data folders.

I know what I need to do, and am probably overcomplicating it with my lack of previous programming. Thank you

Comment: Can You show `print(folders)` output? there is also `>>> glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)
['2.txt', 'sub/3.txt']`

Comment: I agree with @Lukasz, providing the folder names you are looking for will be helpful. You can also run `tree` from command line in the main directory. This will print all the folders and subdirectories so we can get an idea of what you're working with

Comment: So i wild put the tree in the for folder in glob.glob part? The output is the name of all the first subfolders. So 1,2,3,4,5... except in the actual subfolders names are dates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what it is you wish to do, but assuming you want to iterate over 2-nested folders and search for .txt files, this code should do it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
import os

rootdir = '/'
txt_files = []
for _, dirs_1_100, _ in os.walk(rootdir):    # iterate through 1-100
    for dir_1_100 in dirs_1_100:
        path_1_100 = os.path.join(rootdir, dir_1_100)
        for _, dirs_A_E, _ in os.walk(path_1_100): # iterate through A-E
            for dir_A_E in dirs_A_E:
                path_A_E = os.path.join(path_1_100, dir_A_E)
                for _, _, files in os.walk(path_A_E):
                    for requested_file in files:
                        if not requested_file.endswith('.txt'):
                            continue
                        else:
                            txt_files.append(os.path.join(dir_A_E, requested_file))
```